# Generating Xcode build on linux machine using GCC

Tags: linux, macos, gcc

i have gcc installed on my linux machine and i have my xcode project on my linux machine.
now is there anyway i can generate a xcodebuild using gcc on linux machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very unlikely - the project file is designed for the sole use of Xcode and its command line friends. You are better off creating a Makefile for use under Non-Mac systems; this will be **much** quicker that trying to determine how the Xcode project file is structured and how to use the information contained within it.